# Visual Studio 2010 Extension Deployment

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2010, vsx

I have created a VS Package Extension.I want to add a folder(contains sub folders) in the package that get packed and get installed with the package?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Include the files in your project with the folder structure you want. Change the "Build Action" of each file to "Content" and set the "Include in VSIX" property to true.